# Importing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop

Tags: vb.net, vba, import, interop

Just wondering how exactly to import this namespace, extensive searching yielded next to no information. The only VB snippet I found was this: http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/B1374D4/E6944922
and it doesn't provide any information on how to import.
I want to use the iVsUIShell.FindToolWindow
to get the IVsWindowFrame pointer in order to bring a toolwindow to the front of the z-order in my project.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing the namespace is just like importing any other namespace. The actuall `dll` name is: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop` which is part of an SDK that you may not have. If you don't have the SDK you will have to get it to get the `dll` to add as a reference to your project and then import the namespace. Another note: it's also an interface which means you must implement it to get all the functions you need in your class. When you do this you are also required to add reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop`, you can click on the down arrow in `VisualStudio` and import the reference.

**Steps To Add the dll...**

1. First locate the .dll and if you can't find it you need to install the SDK.
2. Next AddReference to your project itself adding the .dll.
3. You will need to `Import` the namespace into your class now. For example: **Imports vi = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop**
4. Inside your class you need to `Implement` it. For example: **Implements vi.IVsUIShell** and then press `Enter`. This will then put all functions required including the `FindToolWindow`  and more...

**Here's a quick screenshot of mine. This all worked just fine for me...**
[image]

Mine (the dll) was located under: `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! Worked perfectly :) 
For some reason I could only access C:\Windows\assembly\GAC from my Chrome browser; that's where I found my .dlls.

Comment: Which SDK do I need to install to have this dll?

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop is part of the Visual Studio SDK

Comment: @Dude0001 yes, but depends on what framework you're targeting and SDK version you're using/installed.